# Catching Scrapy warnings and putting them into items

Tags: python, scrapy

I am getting the following warning during scraping:

```
2019-01-04 05:54:43 [scrapy.core.downloader.tls] WARNING: Remote certificate is not valid for hostname ...
```

I would like to store it in my item field, but have no idea how to catch for a specific request. I managed to deal with catching errors through `errback` in `scrapy.Request` in the following way:

```
def errback(self, failure):

     item = BaseItem()

     item['error'] = failure.type.__name__
     item['url'] = failure.request.url

     yield item
```

Any idea how can I catch warnings and add put them into  `item['warning']`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.
Scrapy doesn't track logging so unless the component updates meta (sometimes it does) with some details, you'll have to update every component with what you want to do.

You could update the location where the warning is raised(`scrapy.core.downloader.tls`) and make it so it would update `response.meta` with some keywords but it seems to be very difficult to do.

Your best bet would be to open up an issue on scrapy's github part - this might a useful feature for future versions of scrapy.

#### Alternatively

As a hack you could read logfile for domain name and if it contains it mark the scraped item:

```
def parse(self, response):
    domain = 'foo.com'
    item = {'bad_cert': False}
    with open('log.out') as f:
        for line in f:
            if 'Remote certificate' in line and domain in line:
                item['bad_cert'] = True
```

Though I'm not sure how reliable this is. On paper the log message should always be written before parse function but logging is not designed to be read during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

By adding this line to settings.py

```
DOWNLOADER_CLIENTCONTEXTFACTORY = 'scrapy.core.downloader.contextfactory.BrowserLikeContextFactory'
```

Scrapy will throw an exception you can catch, instead of just giving a warning when there's a problem like that with an SSL certificate.

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#downloader-clientcontextfactory